# Google Apps script to automate copies of Google Slides document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm trying to get a Google Apps script set up to automate saving of copies of a Google Slides document into a Drive folder each week. I realise that Slides is always backed up but I want to save a weekly copy of a constantly evolving document for reference.

Here's the script I'm trying to run:

```
function makeCopy() {

  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as
// year-month-date hour-minute-second
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone , "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy"
// followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
  var name = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;

// gets the destination folder by their ID. REPLACE
// xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with your folder's ID
// that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive
// and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("MyFolderID");

// gets the current Google Sheet file
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId())

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
  file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You use `DocumentApp` which is for Google Docs, not slides. Instead, it should be `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()`.

Instead of hard-coding the folder ID, you can also use `DriveApp` to get the current file folder if you want to keep them together by using [.getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getId()) and [.getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String)) followed by [.getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getParents()). Although if you want to keep the copies in a separate folder then ignore this.